# Upload Geotiff or Shapefile to Snowflake through streamlit

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I am uploading a geotiff file from my streamlit app using st.file_uploader. How to upload this file to snowflake DB. Is it possible to do so? for now its geotiff but file type can be shape file also.
Please guide.

I have connected my streamlit app to snowflake using snowflake-connector. I have tried uploading csv from streamlit app. and it works. But i am stuck at other file types(tiff,shp) like mentioned.

Comment: Hi. - can you update your question to explain what you mean by “store this file to snowflake DB”? As Snowflake isn’t a file storage tool I’m assuming you mean copy the data into a table (though I suppose you could mean you want to upload the file to a stage)? If you want to store the data in a table then what is the structure of the file, the structure of the table and how do you want to map one to the other?

Comment: Yes. i want to upload my EO data file (geotiff, shape) to snowflake through a streamlit app. Is this possible. At this stage i don't even know what would be the structure of my table as it depends on the uploaded file type.

Comment: If it’s possible to upload the file to Snowflake using pure Snowflake capabilities then it’s also possible to do this using Streamlit